# Rails ActiveAdmin index formatting numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to have my numbers right aligned and with a thousands separator.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Thing do
  index do
    column :id
    column :amount  #  need to make this fomatted nicely

    default_actions
 end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass a block to the column.

```
column :amount do |thing|
  div :class => "amount" do
    number_to_currency thing.amount
  end
end
```

css

```
.amount {
  text-align :right;
}
```

This railscast goes through some pretty good info too http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast

Answer (score 5):

Alternately:

```
column :amount, :class => 'text-right' do |thing|
  number_to_currency thing.amount
end
```

then in your CSS

```
.text-right { text-align: right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Active Admin Addons gem](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons) to improve the UI

https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/number-formatting.md